# Getting key from object for Map using object and interface

Tags: java, interface, guava

I have a Table class that implements a ForwardingMultimap of a certain type of object. I was wondering if it was over-doing it to create an interface that extracted the key from the object so it wouldn't be annoying for the caller to handle "Entry" objects when they call "values". Or would it just be better to have the caller put the object and key in themselves? If this is okay, would creating a separate class to handle each key like below be better, or should the caller implement it themselves ?

```
public class CustomObject {
    public String propertyOne;
    public int propertyTwo;

}

public interface ITableAggKey {
    Object getKey(CustomObject customObj);
}

public class Table extends ForwardingMultimap<Object, CustomObject> {
    Multimap m_map;
    public Table(ITableAggKey aggKey){
        m_map = HashMultimap.create();
        m_aggKey = aggKey;
    }
    public boolean put(CustomObject obj) {
        m_map.put(m_aggKey.getKey(obj), obj);
    }
}

public class CustomObjectAggKeys {
    public static final aggKeyOne = new ITableAggKey(){
        @Overide
        public Object getKey(CustomObject obj){
            return obj.propertyOne;
        }
    };

    public static final aggKeyOne = new ITableAggKey(){
        @Overide
        public Object getKey(CustomObject obj){
            return obj.propertyTwo;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Table<K, T> extends ForwardingMultimap<K, T> {
    Multimap<K, T> m_map;
    Function<T, K> m_aggKey;
    public Table(Function<T, K> aggKey){
        m_map = HashMultimap.create();
        m_aggKey = aggKey;
    }
    public boolean put(T obj) {
        m_map.put(m_aggKey.apply(obj), obj);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Table<String, CustomObject> IndexOne = new Table<>(x -> x.propertyOne);
    Table<Integer, CustomObject> IndexTwo = new Table<>(x -> x.propertyTwo);
}
```

If you cannot use Java8.  Add Function interface.

```
public interface Function<T, K> {
    K apply(T arg);
}
```

And

```
    Table<String, CustomObject> indexOne = new Table<>(new Function<CustomObject, String>() {
        @Override public String apply(CustomObject obj) {
            return obj.propertyOne;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have ability to use java 8 quite yet. This wouldn't change your advice would it?